# streamlit text_area customization

Tags: css, streamlit

I’m trying to customize `st.text_area` to a specific width and height using CSS - but, it’s not being responsive to changes to width and height. is there an alternate approach that I can try?

```py
def main():
    # Custom CSS to modify the textarea width and height
    custom_css = '''
    <style>
        textarea.stTextArea {
            width: 800px !important;
            height: 400px !important;
        }
    </style>
    '''

    st.write(custom_css, unsafe_allow_html=True)

    st.title("Custom Textarea Width and Height")
    user_input = st.text_area("Type your text here:")

    st.subheader("You typed:")
    st.write(user_input)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [**`markdown`**](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/text/st.markdown) for style or html syntax instead of `write`, and also make sure you get the right class.
You can also utilize the `height` parameter to set the height. In that
case you wouldn't need the `textarea.st-cl` part of the costume css.

```
custom_css = '''
    <style>
        div.css-1om1ktf.e1y61itm0 {
          width: 800px;
        }
        textarea.st-cl {
          height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
    '''
st.markdown(custom_css, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Or:

```py
custom_css = '''
    <style>
        div.css-1om1ktf.e1y61itm0 {
          width: 800px;
        }
    </style>
    '''
st.markdown(custom_css, unsafe_allow_html=True)
user_input = st.text_area("Type your text here:", height=400)
```

---

[image]