# How to make streamlit text area wider?

Tags: streamlit

even in wide mode (`st.set_page_config(layout="wide")`) the text fields in streamlit have a fixed max width leading to non-pretty results in some cases:

[image]

Is there a way to adjust the width? idealy to 100% of the screen width?

I tried `st.markdown`, but it seems to have the same limitation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [streamlit text\_area customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75944069/streamlit-text-area-customization)